# Issue in Injecting the service in Lazy load module service

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

Hi I have created lazy load module with LazyService service and I want to inject EagerService which we included in app module. after that when we are running the application i am seeing the below error.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Can't resolve all
>   parameters for LazyService: (?).
>        Error: Can't resolve all parameters for LazyService: (?)

created lazyloadservie and included in lazyload provider below

app/lazy/lazy.module.ts

```
...
import { LazyService } from './lazy.service';

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [LazyService]
})
export class LazyModule {}
```

injected the eagerService which loaded during app load

app/lazy/Lazy.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { EagerService} from '@angular/eager.service';

@Injectable()
export class LazyService{

  constructor(private eagerService: EagerService)
  counter = 0;
  eagerValue = this.eagerService.value;
}
```

Accessing the variables from lazyservice in lazy component

app/lazy/lazy.component.ts

```
import { LazyService} from './lazy.service';

export class LazyComponent {

  constructor(public lazyService: LazyService) {}

  increaseCounter() {
    this.lazyService.counter += 1;
  }
}
```

included eagerService in App module

app/app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [EagerService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

created eager service with class variable

app/eager.service.ts

```
export class EagerService{
  constructor()
  value = "vale from eager service";
}
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: It looks like in your Lazy.service.ts you're trying to inject your EagerService, but did not declare the EagerService as injectable in eager.service.ts by importing Injectable and using the @Injectable decorator.